# encode': "\\x90" on UTF-8 (Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError) Prawn

Tags: ruby

i'm using prawn to generate a pdf document with all the code from my application (juridic issues) and i'm having a actual hard time that has to do with the fonrts implemented, someone knows how could i solve this?

For reference, the error code is

```
`[...]encode': "\\x90" on UTF-8 (Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError)
```

and the code that generates the error seem

```
pdf.text hash.keys.first, style: :bold
```

I have configured the font to Times-Roman, any other generate encoding errors as well

```
pdf.font "Times-Roman"
```

And i've already tried to append encode('utf-8') and force_encode('utf-8') at the strings that are genereting the errors

EDIT:

For specifics, some of the strings that are generating problems are

```
function removeEspeciais($string) {
// matriz de entrada
$what = array( 'ä','ã','à','á','â','ê','ë','è','é','ï','ì','í','ö','õ','ò','ó','ô','ü','ù','ú','û','À','Á','É','Í','Ó','Ú','ñ','Ñ','ç','Ç');
// matriz de saída
$by   = array( 'a','a','a','a','a','e','e','e','e','i','i','i','o','o','o','o','o','u','u','u','u','A','A','E','I','O','U','n','n','c','C' );
// devolver a string
return str_replace($what, $by, $string);
```

}

Or

```
17.1.   Nfe.png
�PNG
```

Comment: What's the value of `hash.keys.first`?

Comment: a string, it comes from a loop that iterates to write the correct string

Comment: What characters does the string contain? What’s the string’s encoding? Be specific, please.

Comment: oh, okay.

It has common brazilian caracters, such as "ç ã õ âêô", it's tipically encoded in utf-8

Comment: _"such as …"_ isn’t that specific. It would really help to have an example that I can just copy and paste which results in the above error. Can you edit your question and add a [mre]?

Comment: okay, i eddited the question

Comment: The code you added isn’t Ruby code. Please give an example `hash` (or just one key) that results in the shown error.

Comment: It's stringified code, so, i want to output exactly this on the PDF

Comment: It’s an encoding issue, i.e. your string contains byte sequences that aren’t valid in UTF-8. It has nothing to do with Prawn or the font you are using. Maybe the string you are trying to write to your PDF comes from another encoding or it somehow got corrupted. Inspecting its `encoding` and its `bytes` should help. (post that data for further help)